# Why is button component's animation transition just working for some buttons?

Tags: unity, c#, animation, unity-ui, animator

I have a main menu scene in which the buttons work using button component's animation transition. I created a simple animation for them that changes their vertex color to blue when selected. The problem is that surprisingly, some of them don't work this way. In fact, they don't even work with other transitions such as color tint.

As you can see in the gif, the animation transitions are working fine. But the truth is that these are (plus a few other buttons in the options menu) the only buttons that have working transitions.

[image]

When you press the quit button, a small panel shows up that asks if you really want to quit the game. This is where the problem appears. Although the yes button should be selected based on the script, it just stays unselected which also shows that the transition animation is not working. I've checked these buttons using animation tab's preview mode and they seem to work fine there but when the actual game starts, they just remain unselected.

[image]

I realized that there should be a big structural difference between the buttons that work and those that don't but I'm not able to find it. To prove this, I changed the transition mode of new game button (that is working fine) and the highlighted and selected color turned blue but when I did the same for the yes button (which cannot be selected), there was no change in the colors.

[image]

[image]

This is the part in my main menu script that controls the exit panel. I don't see any problems in the script as I don't in the editor. But still, some of the buttons can't be selected when the condition is due (All the game objects are assigned in the inspector).

```
   public void OpenExitPanel()
    {
        exitPanel.SetActive(true);
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(exitPanelFirstButton);
        mainMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void CloseExitPanel()
    {
        exitPanel.SetActive(false);
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(exitPanelClosedButton);
        mainMenu.SetActive(true);
    }
```

I also tried creating new buttons (Text Mesh Pro) but again, some of the transitions work and some don't.

This problem is also present in the pause menu but unlike the main menu, none of the buttons can be selected there. I even used Debug.Log to check and see if the first button is selected and it was; but still the animation transition doesn't work.

I believe that this is a Unity bug but I decided to ask it here just to see if I'm missing something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe first try with a different Unity year-version to see if this is a Unity bug.

Comment: Also try setting selected game object in the next frame after you set it to null. Sometimes lifecycle of Unity UI object messes things. (That is, try calling `EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(exitPanelClosedButton);` next frame using a Coroutine of 1 frame and see if it helps).

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I upgraded my version from 2020.3.24f1 to 2020.3.27f1 but that didn't help. If I upgrade or downgrade to a different year, the project will most likely be messed up.

Also, about using a Coroutine, I'm not sure if that can fix the problem since the working buttons don't use it but I'll give it a try. I need to start it in `OpenExitPanel` function because the exit panel can't be closed now. I wrote something and updated the code but it's not working. Is it possible to tell me what part of the code is wrong? I'm not the best at coding :)

Comment: You are welcome. You can (should) try a different year version on a copy of the project in a separate folder. Otherwise, you can revert via git but the Library gets messed up. Your coroutine looks fine so the problem should be something else (I had a similar issue with dropdown animations and next frame trick had solved the issue). In some cases recreating the object from the scratch, or deleting the broken one and copying a working one could help.

Comment: Another question, is the "Yes" button clickable (i.e. functional except the color animation)? If the game object order in the hierarchy is incorrect the pop-up menu background may be blocking the UI hover and click. This could be the case if the background image is on the parent game object. If this is the case make an empty parent, and order background and buttons as its child game objects where the background game object is the first child.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I can copy the project. Do you recommend downloading the latest LTS or the 2021 version? Because last time, I upgraded to the latest LTS and it didn't change anything. By the way, I commented the coroutine since it doesn't solve the issue. Also, the problem wasn't solved by recreating or duplicating the working buttons (which I just did now).

Comment: About your question, yes, it's clickable functionally (in terms of the code and On Click function just like other buttons and it's for quitting the game). I just checked the hierarchy and it's correct based on what you said. So that can't be the source but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I just noticed that the quit button remains selected when the exit panel opens and I can still navigate the buttons (up or down). I think this could be the reason why the "yes" button can't be selected. This means that the `EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);` line in `OpenExitPanel` function doesn't work for some reason. And this is weird. The thing that is stranger is that the pause menu buttons also can't be selected and there's no other buttons before them like here. It seems like changing the Unity version is my only option now.

Comment: Use debugger to see what `EventSystem.current` points to in each step. Looks like the pop-up is unable to take control somehow. Maybe you should try disabling the menu in the background. Also not only buttons, but an image on a parent object (pop-up background in this case) can block interaction. Disable "raycast block" option of the image for a quick check.

Comment: Also, coroutine should be `public IEnumerator NextFrame()
    {
        yield return null;
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(exitPanelFirstButton);
    }
`. No need for the additional coroutine.

Comment: Okay. I figured it out. The buttons weren't working because of a weird mistake that I made. For the OnClick() function, I had assigned set activate object instead of `OpenExitPanel()` function. That was why it wasn't working. Thank you very much Guney for your help! I'll also post the answer soon.

Comment: I just had a quick question about a related problem that occurred after this. When the exit panel opens and I press "no", the panel closes and the quit button becomes selected (blue) as expected. But it stays blue even when I navigate up or down. I'm thinking of writing an if and else statement to deselect the quit button when I navigate the buttons but I don't know how to write that if statement. It should be like: if `exitPanelClosedButton` is selected and I navigated the buttons (up or down), deselect `exitPanelClosedButton` and select the chosen button. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. I forgot to assign the function in the On Click() function in the inspector of the quit button. I mistakenly had assigned SetActive() function. Now it works.

PS: Be sure to use the code in the question. There is no need to use the coroutine for making this to work.

[image]